# "export 'Content' was not found in 'native-base'

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have installed native-base and trying to use below and I am getting the following error.

```
./components/pages/Hero.js:21:11
"export 'Content' was not found in 'native-base'
  19 | const Hero = () => (
  20 |      <Container style={styles.container}>
> 21 |           <Content contentContainerStyle={styles.content}>
     |           ^
  22 |                <Text h4>Find Schools Near You! {"\n"} </Text>
  23 |                <AppLogo />
  24 |           </Content>
```

I have cleaned up the package.lock.json and reinstalled the package yet facing this issue. How can i get past this?